# How to use Ionic Popup with scope in Controller As syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I have an Angular controller setup using Controller as syntax and I need to create an Ionic Popup with a bound data field from one the methods. What I can't figure out is how to set the scope of the popup for the data-binding. I found [this](http://codepen.io/blackjid/pen/EaKXjE) example but it seems really messy to me to use both this and $scope. Is there a better way to do this or should I just go back to the $scope method?

My controller looks like this (with questions marked):

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function ($ionicPopup) {
    // Properties ===========
    this.resetData = {};

    // Methods ==============
    this.forgotPassword = function () {
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="<What goes here?>.resetData.resetEmail">',
            title: 'Please enter your e-mail address',
            scope: <What goes here?>
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        console.log("Password reset:" + <What goes here?>.resetData);
                    }
                },
                { text: 'Cancel' }
            ]
        });
    }
})
```

And my template looks like:

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign In">
    <ion-content has-bouncing="false" ng-controller="AccountCtrl as account">
        <a href="#" ng-click="account.forgotPassword()">Forgot your password?</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. 
Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that example they inject `$scope` so they can assign it as the `scope` property in the popup `show` options.

Maybe if I clear up what the "controller as" syntax is actually doing, you won't feel like it's so messy :)

When you do `ng-controller="myController as ctrl"`, all you're doing is declaring a variable called `ctrl` on the `$scope` for that controller and setting it's value to the `this` for that controller. Doing "myController as ctrl" is literally exactly the same as doing it without the "as" shortcut like this:

```
<!-- markup -->
<div ng-controller="myController"></div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
// controller
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.ctrl = this;
});
```

The only difference when you do "myController as ctrl" is that `$scope.ctrl = this` just happens for you behind the scenes.

Check out [this demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/kJqbB) for proof that they are one and the same.

What they are doing in the demo you linked appears to be totally fine in my opinion ;)

Here's a blog post I wrote about "controller as" if you're interested: http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for explaining that and the really clear, simple example! I'm just trying to get my head around Angular and Ionic and some of the constructs are definitely not obvious. I'll check out or blog post too.

Comment: Glad I could help! I agree that a lot of both Angular and Ionic are not well-documented :/

Comment: One more quick question if you can Chev. How might I call a method of the controller created with "this" from the onTap handler? I'm thinking I can't as the method is only on the specific instance (calling it using the instance name means putting knowledge of the view in the controller which is not a good idea). Correct?

Comment: @jason You'll need to provide more details I think. Feel free to start a new question and link to it here :)

Comment: It's okay, I need to do a bit more research first I think. Thanks Chev!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to hit me up if you need anything else. alex.ford@codetunnel.com